# Find eigenvalues & eigenvectors for an integral.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, eigenfunctions

Can anyone please explain me how to solve it?

Find the nonzero eigenvalues and the corresponding eigenvectors:

$T:[-1,1]\rightarrow[-1,1]$

$$T((f(x))=\int_{-1}^1(x^2 y + y^2 x) f(y) \, dy$$

Comment: Why did you mess up the MathJax I just fixed?

Comment: Sorry, i'm new on this website and i don't know how to properly use it. I wanted to add a term which i forgot to put the first time between the parantheses.

Comment: Is it now right like this?

Comment: yes, but the MathJax probably isn't right

Comment: Do you know how MathJax works or respectively LaTeX or could you at least explain what is not right now?

Comment: now it seems to be right

Comment: What is $*$ operator?

Answer (score 1):

The eigenvalues are $$\pm\sqrt{\frac{4}{15}}$$ with corresponding eigenvectors $$f\left(x\right)=\sqrt{5}x^{2}\pm\sqrt{3}x$$ We get this by noting that $Tf\left(x\right)$ is always a quadratic, so eigenvectors must be quadratics. We insert $f\left(x\right)$ in this form and solve the algebraic equations.

Comment: Can you explain me how to solve it step by step? I have no idea how to solve this type of problems since we didn't use integrals in the linear algebra classes, but the teacher got mad at us and asked this question at the exam.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that $T$ is acting on the space of continuous functions on $[-1,1]$, i.e. $T : C[-1,1] \to C[-1,1]$.

The eigenvalues of $T$ are $0$ and $\pm\sqrt{\frac4{15}}$.

Assume that $Tf = \lambda f$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$.

We have

$$\lambda f(x) = (Tf)(x) = \int_{-1}^1 (x^2y + y^2x)f(y)\,dy$$

so $f$ is differentiable and we have

$$\lambda f'(x) = (Tf)(x) = \int_{-1}^1 (2xy + y^2)f(y)\,dy$$

so $f'$ is differentiable and we have

$$\lambda f''(x) = (Tf)(x) = \int_{-1}^1 2yf(y)\,dy = \text{const.}$$

If $\lambda \ne 0$, then $f'' = \text{const.}$ so $f$ is a quadratic polynomial $f(x) = Ax^2 + Bx + C$.

We get $$A = \frac12f''(x) = \frac1\lambda \int_{-1}^1 yf(y)\,dy = \frac1\lambda \frac{2B}3$$
$$B = f'(0) = \frac1\lambda \int_{-1}^1 y^2f(y)\,dy = \frac1\lambda\left(\frac{2A}5 + \frac{2C}3\right)$$
$$C = f(0) = 0$$

so if we fix $A = 1$ we get $\lambda = \frac43 B$ and $\lambda B = \frac25$ so $$\lambda = \pm \sqrt{\frac{4}{15}}$$

with eigenvectors $f(x) = x^2 \pm \frac12\sqrt{\frac35}$.

If $\lambda = 0$ then we get the condition

$$0 = x^2 \int_{-1}^1 yf(y) \,dy + x \int_{-1}^1 y^2f(y)\,dy$$

so $\int_{-1}^1 yf(y) \,dy = \int_{-1}^1 y^2f(y)\,dy = 0$.

This is indeed an eigenvalue with an eigenvector e.g. $$f(x) = x^3-\frac53 x^2 - \frac35 x + 1$$

Answer (score 0):

Since $$Tf\left(x\right)=x^2\int_{-1}^{1} yf\left(y\right)dy+x\int_{-1}^{1} y^2f\left(y\right)dy$$
we have that $Tf\left(x\right)=ax^2+bx$ for some $a,b$. Hence, if $f\left(x\right)$ is an eigenvector it must take this form. Plugging this in we get $$Tf\left(x\right)=x^2\int_{-1}^{1} y\left(ay^2+by\right)dy+x\int_{-1}^{1} y^2\left(ay^2+by\right)dy$$
$$=x^2\int_{-1}^{1} \left(ay^3+by^2\right)dy+x\int_{-1}^{1} \left(ay^4+by^3\right)dy$$
$$=bx^2\int_{-1}^{1} \left(y^2\right)dy+ax\int_{-1}^{1} \left(y^4\right)dy$$
$$=\frac {2} {3} bx^2+\frac {2} {5} ax$$
and if this is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda$ then we find $\lambda a=\frac {2} {3} b$ and $\lambda b=\frac {2} {5} a$. Solving this for $\lambda$ and $a,b$ we find the eigenvalues and the eigenvectors in my other post.

Answer (score 0):

$$Tf(x)=x^2\int_{-1}^{1}yf(y)dy+x\int_{-1}^{1}y^2f(y)dy$$then any eigenfunction is of form$$f(x)=ax^2+bx$$by substitution we obtain$$Tf(x)=\dfrac{2}{3}bx^2+\dfrac{2}{5}ax=\lambda ax^2+\lambda bx$$which means that $$\dfrac{2}{3}b=\lambda a\\\dfrac{2}{5}a=\lambda b$$one trivial eigenfunction is $f(x)=0$ the other ones exist when $$\dfrac{4}{15}=\lambda^2\\\lambda=\pm\dfrac{2}{\sqrt 15}$$therefore $$f(x)=ax^2\pm\sqrt{\dfrac{3}{5}}ax$$ corresponding to $\lambda=\pm\dfrac{2}{\sqrt {15}}$ respectively